# Angular 2: Observables not working on login

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Hello i'm trying to show the logged in user's username inside the navbar, this is working but it doesn't update right after you login or logout. To make this work i started using rxjs's Subject and Observable, this works when i logout but it doesn't when i login. I'm still quite new to angular, does anybody know what the problem could be?

**navbar.component.ts**

```
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private toastrService: ToastrService
  ) {
    this.auth = authService;
    authService.isLoggedIn().subscribe(
      status => {
        if(status == false) {
          this.user = null;
        } else {
          this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
            this.user = profile.user;
          })
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
  private logger = new Subject<boolean>();

  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.logger.asObservable();
  }

  setLoginLogger(status){
    this.logger.next(status)
  }

  logout(){
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
    this.logger.next(false);
  }

  authenticateUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, {headers: headers})
          .map(res => res.json());
  }

  storeUserData(token, user){
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
 onLoginSubmit(){
    const user = {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }

    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe((data) => {
      if(data.success){
        this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);

        if(localStorage.getItem('id_token')){
          this.authService.setLoginLogger(true);
          this.router.navigate(['']);
          this.toastrService.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!');
        }

      } else {
        this.toastrService.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!');

        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **ChangeDetectorRef** to reflect the changes in **navbar.component.ts**.

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(
private authService: AuthService,
private router: Router,
private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
private toastrService: ToastrService,private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
this.auth = authService;
authService.isLoggedIn().subscribe(
  status => {
    if(status == false) {
      this.user = null;
    } else {
      this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
        this.user = profile.user;
        //reflect the changes
         this.changeDetectorRef.detach();
         setInterval(() => {
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
         }, 1000);
      })
    }
  }
)
 }
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing the problem, i had to delete the providers inside my components because it was already provided to my **app.module.ts**.